# Что такое конекшены с сервером, как работают, зачем нужны и как использовать?

Tags: .net, http, веб-сервер, браузер, tcp

До этого знал что есть HTTP запросы, думал что хорошо их понимаю... И практически их использовал с веб сокетами, которые не очень понимал. Использую С#/.NET, c практической стороны можно говорить в контексте этого стека.
Узнал что есть некие 'соединения'... Услышал что с Http1.1 все запросы по умолчанию снабжены заголовком Connection: keep-alive  без явного добавления. То есть любой запрос порождает соединение, это ломает мое примитивное понимание запросов, а на место пустоты понимания ничего не приходит...

1. В чем разница между просто последовательными запросами из Http1.0 и этими соединениями? Не понимаю зачем его 'держать' и что это вообще значит. Где тут выгода?
   Сейчас 'держать соединение' представляю по аналогии переиспользвания инстанса HttpClient, а не создавать новый каждый раз. Только тут на клиентах в рамках браузеров/мобильных либ TCP клиенты, которые работают не явно из кода который пишут фронтендщики. Это верное понимание или тут есть некий контекст концепций из описания протокола? Как тогда на стороне сервера может быть контроль количества соединений, если их количество должно быть известно только на клиенте?
2. То есть эти клиенты создавая инстансы для запросов на сервер, отслеживают появления в ответе
   заголовка Connection: close для 'вызова Dispose' у инстанса, и прекращении его использования?
3. Кто отправляет заголовок Connection: close? Веб сервера nginx, iis, kestrel или это делает ASP под капотом? Можно и руками добавлять используя ASP Core... но ни умения ни понимания зачем это нужно нет. Аналогично хотелось бы узнать какая часть должна отслеживать хедер Connection: keep-alive.
4. Напишите, пожалуйста, что еще знаете в контексте вопроса 'Что такое конекшены с сервером, как работают, зачем нужны и как использовать?'. Любой ваш опыт или хорошие ссылки будет интересны.

Comment: Начнем с того, что это TCP, идем в вики `Механизм TCP предоставляет поток данных с предварительной установкой соединения`, то есть любой запрос на любой сайт - это первым делом подключение к нему, а уже потом манипуляция пакетами. Подключение, это весьма дорогая операция, занимающая прилично так времени. Ну вот и придумали "постоянное соединение", которое использует одно соединение клиент<>сервер для взаимодействия с пакетами. Это кстати одна из причин, почему не стоит постоянно создавать `HttpClient`, вот гляньте просто [этот](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3zGFhl) код, что видите?

Comment: Сейчас все соединения по умолчанию постоянные, они закрываются автоматически по истечению таймера OS, либо по запросу клиента. Если мне память не изменяет, то за этим следит сама OS (можете, к примеру глянуть в Windows все соединения, прописав в консоль `netstat`). Код выше посмотрели? Что увидели? Верно, в первом случае мы постоянно создаем новый клиент с новым соединением, а как я писал выше - соединение, дорогостоящая операция, что в итоге нам дало 200+мс время ожидания каждого запроса, а вот если соединение одно, то первый ~200, остальные в два раза меньше (код советую запускать у себя!).

Comment: Evgeniy, что за соединения вы дали ответ (это ТСP соединения), спасибо! Теоретически понятно в чем выгода, не нужно будет часть действий каждый раз осуществлять. Хотя код не очень стабильно время выдает и сложно трактовать его результаты. netstat - дал список, можно изучать :)

Comment: А вот OS как я понял следит, но не вмешиваеться пока все хорошо веб сервера разруливают. Хотя, Вы писали  про таймеры, нужно смотреть...

Comment: `не очень стабильно` - это проблемы онлайн компилятора, запустите у себя, вбейте любой адрес, укажите любое число, и смотрите результат (у меня постоянно [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE2jW.png). `netstat - дал список` - отсортируйте там по  адресу (прим: `netstat -n | select-string -pattern "111.111.111.111"`) и последите за жизнью запросов. `OS как я понял следит` - да, даже если вы сами напишете `.Dispose()` или аналогичное, то запрос будет еще висеть на уровне OS со статусом `TIME_WAIT` некое время (настройка OS). Сам же коннект, если долго не используется - закрывается по таймауту.

Comment: Да. У меня локально тенденции похожие http://prntscr.com/1vrq66w. Странно что первый запрос, в первом случае тоже дольше намного чем последующие. А вот решил цикл до 500 созданий поднять, но в netstat такой большей активности не видно, но она есть (20-40 записей ESTABLISHED).

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто.

Каждый раз, когда браузер "отрисовывает" страницу, это порождает "шквал" запросов на множество серверов. Потому что страница устроена очень сложно: это довольно много js-кода и десятки картинок с разных серверов.

Плюс к этому, этот js код начинает ajax-ом стучаться в разные методы бэкэнда.

Причем, по хорошему это должно идти не по http, а по https.

А теперь вспомним, что такое https. Это значит, что при устновлении каждого tcp-соединения происходит обмен открытыми ключами для создания зашифрованного канала - ssl handshaking.

И просто в HTTP 1.1 можно провести этот обмен ключами один раз между клиентом и конкретным сервером, а потом пользоваться уже установленным tcp соединением, не начиная всю эту возню с ключами заново при следующем обращении к тому же самому серверу.

Этот процесс абсолютно прозрачен как для сервера, так и для клиента. Более того, во многих случаях этот tcp-коннекшн существует между клиентом и энджинксом, который стоит "на входе" и служит системой распределения нагрузки, а сам nginx уже раскидывает запросы по целой ферме серверов для обслуживания бэкэнд-запросов, которые прячутся за ним.

Откровенно говоря, я не знаю, кто  отправляет заголовок Connection: close. tcp соединения имеют свойство "протухать" - ну, перешли вы через дорогу, сотовый телефон подключился к другой вышке, а трансляция потоковой музыки через спотифай продолжается. Просто на более низком уровне, чем логика клиента, tcp коннекшн порвался и установился заново, когда понадобилось протащить с сервера следующий кусочек музкального потока.

В Вашем вопросе собрано несколько вопросов, если у Вас остались сомнения по поводу тех вопросов, на которые я не ответил - уточните исходный вопрос, подумаем еще.

Кстати, только что в голову пришел простой и любопытный эксперимент. Сделем простую страницу на сервере, поддерживающем http 1.1. Посмотрим на статистику  открытых соединений на клиенте - ну,там, при помощи `ss` или более олдскульно - через netstat. Теперь откроем страницу в браузере.

Если я прав - то после полной загрузки страницы, когда уже всё прогрузилось и браузер ничего не ждёт, должны остаться одно или несколько открытых tcp-соединений с сервером, откуда была загружена страница. Это как раз позволило  бы, если бы клиент захотел что то еще загрузить, воспользоваться уже открытым коннектом.

Если же мои представления не верны - я буду рад, если кто то меня поправит :-) - о, пока я писал ответ, в коментариях к вопросу сказали всё то же самое , только короче!